# Django TypeError missing 1 required positional argument: 'person_id'

Tags: django

I'm trying to write a simple banking app using **Django** and I'm stuck on a strange error, missing positional argument. Any help would be much appreciated. The other templates and views work okay. The problem happens when I go to the login page.

The full error is:

```
TypeError at /banking/login/

login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'person_id'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/banking/login/
Django Version:     1.9
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'person_id'

Exception Location:     /home/soupdragon/DJapps/env/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response, line 147
Python Executable:  /home/soupdragon/DJapps/env/bin/python
Python Version:     3.4.3
Python Path:    

'/home/soupdragon/DJapps/banking/mybank',
'/home/soupdragon/DJapps/env/lib/python3.4',
'/home/soupdragon/DJapps/env/lib/python3.4/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
'/home/soupdragon/DJapps/env/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
'/usr/lib/python3.4',
'/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
'/home/soupdragon/DJapps/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages']

Server time:    Fri, 12 Aug 2016 17:39:38 +0000
```

The stack trace is:

```
Internal Server Error: /banking/login/
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/home/soupdragon/DJapps/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django
/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/soupdragon/DJapps/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django 
/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'person_id'
[12/Aug/2016 17:39:38] "GET /banking/login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 6010
```

The urls file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'banking'
urlpatterns = [
# ex: /banking/deposit
url(r'^deposit/$', views.deposit, name='deposit'),
# ex: /banking/
url(r'^$', views.hello, name='hello'),
# ex: /banking/login
url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
# ex: /banking/transfer
url(r'^transfer/$', views.transfer, name='transfer'),
# ex: /banking/withdraw
url(r'^withdraw/$', views.withdraw, name='withdraw'),
# ex: /banking/welcome
url(r'^welcome/$', views.welcome, name='welcome'),
]
```

The models file is:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Person(models.Model):
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length=4,default="Bob")
     last_name = models.CharField(max_length=6,default="Smith")
     login_name = models.CharField(max_length=3,default="me")
     password = models.CharField(max_length=7, default="password")
     person_text = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="Bob Smith") 

     def get_first_name(self):
         return self.first_name

     def get_last_name(self):
         return self.last_name

     def get_login_name(self):
         return self.login_name

     def get_password(self):
         return self.password

     def __str__(self):
         return self.person_text

class Account1(models.Model):
    account_number = models.IntegerField(default=12345678)
    bank_balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,
    decimal_places=2,default=12.99)
    interest_rate = models.IntegerField(default=2)
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=16, default="Current
                    Account")
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person,                     on_delete=models.CASCADE,default="") 

    def get_account_number(self):
        return self.account_number

    def get_bank_balance(self):
        return self.bank_balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.bank_balance = self.bank_balance + amount
        return

    def get_interest_rate(self):
        return self.interest_rate

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.bank_balance = self.bank_balance - amount
        return

    #def __str__(self):
    #   return self.account_name
```

The views file is:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.template import loader

from .models import Person, Account1

# Create your views here.
def deposit(request):
    person = Person
    account1 = Account1
    context = {'account1':account1,'person':person}
    template = loader.get_template('banking/deposit.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello.")

def login(request, person_id):
    person = get_object_or_404(Person, pk=person_id) 
    try:
        selected_login = person.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['login'])
        selected_password = person.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['password'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'banking/login.html', {
            'person': person,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('banking:welcome',
            args=(question.id,)))


def transfer(request):
    person = Person
    account1 = Account1
    context = {'account1':account1,'person':person}
    template = loader.get_template('banking/transfer.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))

def welcome(request):
    person = Person
    account1 = Account1
    context = {'account1':account1,'person':person}
    template = loader.get_template('banking/welcome.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))

def withdraw(request):
    person = Person
    account1 = Account1
    context = {'account1':account1,'person':person}
    template = loader.get_template('banking/withdraw.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))
```

The login template is:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Deposit Money</title>
 <h1 id="bluetext">Please Select Account to Deposit into</h1>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/deposit.css' %}">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap
 /3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery
 /1.11/jquery.min.js"></script>  
 <style type="text/css"></style>
 </head> 
 <body>

 <div class="container-fluid" style="background-image:
 url('login.jpg'); width: 100%; height: 300px; background-size:cover;"> 
 </div>

<form action="{% url 'banking:login' person.id %}" method="post">
<fieldset>
{% csrf_token %}
<legend>Your details:</legend>
<hr></hr>
Username:<input type="text" id="username" name="username" size="33
</input>
<br></br>
Password:<input type="text" id="password" name="password" size="33">
</input>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please use the built-in authentication system. Using an authentication system that's not vetted for security not only puts your site at risk, it can also reveal private information or put your user's accounts on other sites at risk. Saving a password as plain text is not secure.

Comment: Your login view is expecting a person_id, for some reason, but you're not capturing that value in the URL. Note that none of this makes any sense at all; you don't have a Choice model and it's not clear why you would check the username and password against that rather than the Person itself. Anyway, as knbk says, you **must not** roll your own authentication.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
def login(request, person_id):
    person = get_object_or_404(Person, pk=person_id)
```

Your view expects `person_id` to be passed from the url but your url pattern doesn't include `person_id`.

Please don't reinvent the wheel - use the built in authentication system. And if you must, you should try to retrieve the `username` and `password` from `request.POST` and use the username to find the correct user (person). Using person_id is probably not the best solution anyway.

Comment: Thank you both so much for your replies. I didn't know there was a built in authentication system. I'll read the documents about that.

Comment: I tried adding selected_login = request.POST.get('login') and selected_username = request.POST.get('username') and got rid of the person_id and updated the urls and it works. Time to read the Django documents!

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, you might want to accept the answer.